# Jobs in Historical Linguistics

Tags: historical-linguistics

As a someone interested in Linguistics, after I leave school I would like to pursue this interest into my later life, as a career, but the majority of my nearby universities only teach the more scientific study of linguistics, where I would more like to explore the more historical form of linguistics, compounding my interest in archaeology and classical languages. The only courses I have found are overseas, especially the Linguistics and Classics course at Edinburgh University. But this is a big life commitment to undertake, especially in pursuit of a career many people say will have not many opportunities for employment. I am hoping that there will be opportunities, because even though I am at a stage most people don't know what they want to do with their lives, I think I have a very real passion for this topic.

Comment: Maybe https://academia.stackexchange.com can help you better. In my opinion, if you really want to pursue a career in a purely academic area like historical linguistics, you should be prepared to relocate to other countries, not just to study but also to find job openings later.

Comment: This is a question for academia.stackexchange indeed. Be very, very aware that (a) humanities is less fashionable than STEM, (b) historical linguistics and classics are much less fashionable than other linguistics and languages, so much less jobs, (c) to get an academic job, you will have to be political and work contacts; and if you're VERY lucky, you'll get a job back in your mother  country; (d) for God's sake, have a Plan B. And C and D.

Comment: If you're seriously interested in historical linguistics, then you must be aware of its close relation to sociolinguistics (which can be thought of as "stop-frame historical linguistics"). You'll need to study that, as well; and that means studying sampling, interviewing, polling, and statistics, not to mention status and class. These are very useful skills, and they dovetail beautifully with both the linguistic and the historical frames of reference; with this kind of background, you can become an expert in practically anything very fast. This might be useful occasionally.